# Mysql optimization issue

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Any guess why this statement is taking too long when handling 300 000 rows. Basically this query is meant for finding duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    a.Id,
    b.Id as sid
FROM 
    csv_temp a
INNER JOIN 
    csv_temp b ON a.firstname = b.firstname AND 
    a.lastname = b.lastname  AND 
   ((a.address = b.address) OR 
    (a.zip = b.zip) OR 
    (a.city = b.city AND a.state = b.state) )
WHERE 
    a.Id <> b.Id AND 
    a.status=2 AND 
    b.status=1 AND 
    a.flag !=1 AND 
    b.flag !=1
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding index for all these column combinations.

Comment: Show explain of query + table creation queries

Comment: it will better if you use millions instead of lakh . thanks

Comment: are all the columns compared indexed?

Comment: yeah i have added all indexes

Comment: @RahulJha Indices on exactly which columns (multi-column or single-column indices)?

Comment: i have uploaded the indices what i have created

Comment: Can you show the `EXPLAIN` of the query?

Comment: Put the OR condition into the where clause and add indices on First and Last Name.

Comment: @Dukeling unfortunately the table is a temporary table and i delete it after whole process. give me some time then i will give you EXPLAIN of the query.

Comment: How about removing inner join and putting all condition inside where?

Comment: Try removing the `address`, `zip`, `city` and `state` check (leave firstname and lastname checks) from the JOIN and putting it in the WHERE. Not sure if it will make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

ORs often seem to have poor performance, and on JOIN conditions I would expect that to be worse. Try having 3 SELECTs (one for each of the ORed conditions) and UNION the results together. Suspect the DISTINCTS are not required either if this is done:-

```
SELECT  
    a.Id,
    b.Id as sid
FROM 
    csv_temp a
INNER JOIN 
    csv_temp b ON a.firstname = b.firstname AND 
    a.lastname = b.lastname  AND 
   a.address = b.address
WHERE 
    a.Id <> b.Id AND 
    a.status=2 AND 
    b.status=1 AND 
    a.flag !=1 AND 
    b.flag !=1
UNION
SELECT  
    a.Id,
    b.Id as sid
FROM 
    csv_temp a
INNER JOIN 
    csv_temp b ON a.firstname = b.firstname AND 
    a.lastname = b.lastname  AND 
    a.zip = b.zip
WHERE 
    a.Id <> b.Id AND 
    a.status=2 AND 
    b.status=1 AND 
    a.flag !=1 AND 
    b.flag !=1
UNION
SELECT  
    a.Id,
    b.Id as sid
FROM 
    csv_temp a
INNER JOIN 
    csv_temp b ON a.firstname = b.firstname AND 
    a.lastname = b.lastname  AND 
    a.city = b.city AND a.state = b.state
WHERE 
    a.Id <> b.Id AND 
    a.status=2 AND 
    b.status=1 AND 
    a.flag !=1 AND 
    b.flag !=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Now check using the Explain Plan after adding indexes on the column which are using in compare